# Like search equivalent possible in BaseX or other XML database?

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm currently transforming XML files into a relational database and doing complex queries, one of them compares a very large (several hundred to 1000+) list of names against the database. Is this sort of operation possible in a native XML database? I like the idea of a format that is ready for display in a browser (as opposed to getting it out of mysql). Would the performance be lousy for this? Also - can you move the results to an archive? I'm currently exploring BaseX.

Comment: several hundred items is not "very large" in the database world. You're likely to be fine.

Comment: Sure you can. In most XML databases, including BaseX, queries are sped up by index structures, similar to RDBMS and NoSQL stores. RESTXQ allows you to write web applications on top of XML databases.